# Google AppEngine Java - getServingUrl for not images

Tags: google-app-engine, url, blob, blobstore

i'm trying to get a servingUrl for a generic Blob (like txt file or pdf) but the provided method works only for images

```
BlobKey blobkey = {my blobkey};
ServingUrlOptions options = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobkey);
String url = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService().getServingUrl(options);
```

Is there a way to get a servingUrl for a generic Blob or the only way i can do this is using the [serve()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreService#serve%28com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey,%20HttpServletResponse%29) method from BlobStore service?

Comment: YEs, servingUrl works only for images

Answer (score 0):

Your alternatives are as you said to either use the `serve` method of the `Blobstore Api`, or to use [Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/storage).

The advantage of using the Blobstore API is that you have more control to serve the file.

However, as you are looking for something similar to `getServingUrl`, cloud storage will meet your needs.

To do so, you create a bucket and configure it to be used from within Appengine. Then you create the upload url by specifying the bucket you want to upload the files to. Then you have a serving url for your file (yo need to change the acls of the particular files you want to serve publicly or if you want to serve all uploaded files you can set the default acls to allow reading for allUsers).